# How to combine single column value from many row by loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run my first query, I get 5 rows of result. The value for row1 is "Day1", row 2 is "Day2" and etc... After that I want combine it to a string as "Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5". But after I run the stored procedure, I get empty result. Below is my stored procedure. How to I solve it? Thanks

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @PeriodID nvarchar(50);
Declare @FinalString nvarchar(80);

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT PeriodID FROM PeriodTable c WHERE c.Active=1

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @PeriodID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @FinalString = @FinalString + @PeriodID + ','

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @PeriodID
END

CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;

print @FinalString 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a cursor.  I think you missed setting the variable to a blank string first so it was null making each row null.  This works:

```
declare @ret varchar(8000)
set @ret = ''

select @ret = @ret+', '+name
from ImagedApps
order by name 

-- take off the first comma and space
select substring(@ret, 3, 8000)
```

Comment: It work great by using simple code. I wonder why I am using complicated code.Thanks